# Concatenate static properties in php

Tags: php, static, concatenation, public

I have two static properties I would like to access outside of a class, the second of which I would like to concatenate with the first.

Ex:

```php
<?php
class Constants {
    public static $varToConcat = "bar";
    public static $concat = "foo " . self::$varToConcat;    // <-- How to concatenate?
}
echo Constants::$concat;
?>
```

The above gives the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in ...../Constants.php on line 4

I've tried:

```php
public static $concat = "foo " . $varToConcat;
public static $concat = "foo " . self::$varToConcat;
public static $concat = "foo " . $this->varToConcat;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Class variable declarations must be a non-evaluated value.

Comment: [Just use *actual* constants?](https://3v4l.org/4sG4l) Actually not exactly sure why this doesn't work with static properties' initializers, since it works with constants'.

Comment: @Jeto Paradigmatically, you are correct. These values will never change; I will use const.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate outside the class do that:

```
<?php

class War
{
    public static $foo = 'Hello';
    public static $bar = 'World';
}

echo War::$foo. ' ' . War::$bar;
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do what you're talking about because `static` cannot be dynamic like that. What you could do is create a static method and get it

```
<?php
class Constants {
    public static $varToConcat = "bar";
    public static $concat = "foo ";

    public static function getConcat() {
        return self::$concat . self::$varToConcat;
    }
}
echo Constants::getConcat();
```